# Is this a sin or not?

Tags: halal-haram, sin

Ok. So I watched a couple of videos about urine sin. I was wandering, if I wiped after I went to the toilet, and then after I went out, a drop of urine fell on my underwear, would that be considered as the urine sin? Or is it just that you must wipe after you go toilet.

Also, if there is some impurity after defecating, but you have wiped with tissue paper (not used water though) is that fine?

Answer (score 0):

Any drop of urine which falls on your clothes is rendered najis and therefore you cannot pray your salah as you are wearing impure clothing. The only time it’s acceptable is when you suffer from a chronic illness such an example would be urine incontinence and the hanafi fiqh states that 5cm can be allowed but anything more Will invalidate your prayer. I’m not sure about your 2nd question but in my opinion I think it’s best to use water as it cleans it better than toilet paper

Comment: So what should I do about the drops of urine to prevent it?

Comment: By the way thanks a lot.

Comment: I still suffer from it and the only way I can sort of control it is by staying 10 mins on toilet. Then leaving tissues thick enough to make sure the urine drops don’t spread. I still get some leakage after but there isn’t anything I can do. I think I should mention that wudu has to be done again at each salah and if anything comes out then you should ignore it. But I’d still get it looked at by a doctor because then you can determine whether this is a uti or urine incontinence. And no problem :)

Comment: Wait, when you say 5cm you mean like radius of the urine drop. Man I just want to make sure that my wudu is not being invalidated.

Comment: Wudu is only invalidated if urine leaks not by having it on your clothes. And yes I believe it’s the radius however I’d recommend looking into it a bit more because I’ve never actually used this 5cm ruling

Comment: You should do wudu with every prayer and also splash water on your underwear or shalwar (It's a sunnah). Most of the time it's the Shaitan giving us doubt about the urine. You should just ignore those doubts.
It happens a lot with me when I'm late from Jamat and Imam is in second/third Rakat and then at that time I get that doubt. If get busy making new wudu I missed the jamat. Which shaitan wanted.